# How to store a token on an account owned by a program?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I'm trying to get a liquidity pool of a token that is own by my program. This would be simple on other blockchains but I admit I'm having a bit of trouble on Solana.

First here is the important part of my Anchor code :

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Test1<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub from: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = from, 
        seeds = [b"tests"],
        bump,
        space = 24
    )]
    pub staked: Account<'info, StakedAccount>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = from, 
        seeds = [b"data123"],
        bump,
        space = 32
    )]
    pub data: Account<'info, DataAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub from_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
     #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = from_ata,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = data
    )]
    pub program_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(
        address = MINT_ACCOUNT
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
```

And here is the instruction to call the program :

```
let txHash = await pg.program.methods
  .test()
  .accounts({
    staked:stakedTest,
    data:stakedTest2,
    from: pg.wallet.publicKey,
    fromAta: ata_user,
    programAta: ata_program,
    mint: MINT_USDC,
    tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    systemProgram:anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
    associatedTokenProgram:SPL_ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_ACCOUNT_PROGRAM_ID,
    rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY
  })
  .rpc();
await logTransaction(txHash);
```

Basically, the idea would be for the token account (program_ata) to be owned by data (a PDA from my program). However, I want my program to authorize only the deposit of a particular token (USDC). That's why I use: associated_token::mint = mint, associated_token::authority = data.

I get this error: "Uncaught error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing".

I'm sure it's from associated_token::mint = mint, associated_token::authority = data. Do you know why I'm getting this error? Is the logic right ?

Thanks

Comment: Does adding ```pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>``` as an account solve the issue? Also, try changing ```associated_token::mint``` to ```token::mint``` (do the same with authority), and report back if that solves your issue

Comment: I already had pub token_program: Program<'info, Token> as an account (I just didn't show it in the snippet). I also tried to replace associated_token::mint to token::mint. But it doesn't work

Comment: With token::mint I get : Uncaught error: Signature verification failed

Comment: Gotcha. Can you provide a snippet of how you're calling this instruction? Also, can you add all the accounts you're including to the #[derive(Accounts)] snippet

Comment: I have edited the original post to add all these informations :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an anchor escrow program for you to use as a reference. The [repo](https://github.com/ironaddicteddog/anchor-escrow).

The notes for the repo are [here](https://solmeet.gen3.network/notes/intro-to-anchor).

You will need to know how Program Derived addresses works in order to understand Solana’s program model.

Comment: Please dont only paste links, but also add the code to do so and explain a bit how it works